# Add border and background to Contact 7 form Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to add a border and a background color to Contact Form 7.  I have used "inspect element" to see what class/ids to target but I have not found one that targets the entire form as a whole.  Everything I've tried (such as .wpcf7-form and .wpcf7) targets the text areas only.  Can someone please help?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful!  I have a follow-up question: why does my form look so bad?  https://www.nycofficesuites.com/new/?page_id=164 my code:  <p>Choose Location<br /> 
[select your-location "Plaza" "Greybar" Flatiron" "Other"] </p>

<p>Meeting Date<br />
[date* MeetingDate]</p>

<p>Name *<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Email *<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Company<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>[textarea Company]

<p>Telephone *<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>[tel* tel-63]

<p>Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>[submit "Send Message"]</p>

Comment: I figured out why that wasn't working.  Now the only problem is the date.  Why is there no drop down calendar?

Comment: I figured out why that wasn't working.  Now the only problem is the date.  Why is there no drop down calendar?  The page https://www.nycofficesuites.com/new/?page_id=164 and the code: `Select Location
[select your-location "Plaza" "Greybar" "Flatiron" "Other"]

Meeting Date
[date* date-926 step:30]

Name *
[text* your-name]

Email *
[email* your-email]

Company
[text your-company]

Telephone *
[tel* tel-63]

Message
[textarea your-message]

[submit "Request Reservation"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surround the form with a div in html:

```
<div class="custom-styling">
    // contact form 7 code here
</div>
```

Then style the `custom-styling` class with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The top-level element of contact form has `wpcf7` class. To style the whole contact form, add style rules for the class selector as like :

```
.wpcf7
{
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
```

For more detailed information, check it out here : http://contactform7.com/styling-contact-form/

Hope it helps you.